# CentOS 7 install PostgreSQL dependency error

Tags: centos, yum, postgresql

When running `yum install postgresql-server.x86_64`, I encounter the following error:

```
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.5()(64bit) for package: postgresql-server-8.1.23-10.el5_10.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: postgresql-8.1.23-10.el5_10.x86_64 (el5_latest)
           Requires: libreadline.so.5()(64bit)
           Available: readline-5.1-3.el5.x86_64 (el5_latest)
               libreadline.so.5()(64bit)
           Installed: readline-6.2-9.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
              ~libreadline.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: postgresql-8.1.23-10.el5_10.x86_64 (el5_latest)
           Requires: libtermcap.so.2()(64bit)
           Available: libtermcap-2.0.8-46.1.x86_64 (el5_latest)
               libtermcap.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: postgresql-server-8.1.23-10.el5_10.x86_64 (el5_latest)
           Requires: libreadline.so.5()(64bit)
           Available: readline-5.1-3.el5.x86_64 (el5_latest)
               libreadline.so.5()(64bit)
           Installed: readline-6.2-9.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
              ~libreadline.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: postgresql-server-8.1.23-10.el5_10.x86_64 (el5_latest)
           Requires: libtermcap.so.2()(64bit)
           Available: libtermcap-2.0.8-46.1.x86_64 (el5_latest)
               libtermcap.so.2()(64bit)
```

My first guess was that I didn't have `readline` installed, but it turns out that this is not the issue:

```
~ % yum list installed|grep readline
readline.x86_64                 6.2-9.el7                              @anaconda
readline-devel.x86_64           6.2-9.el7                              @base
```

I am assuming there is still a missing dependency.

The error message itself is a bit cryptic - what can I do to resolve this and resume installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages that you are trying to install actually depend on an older version of CentOS.

Notice in your error message, you reference the `el5_latest` repository, which is for CentOS 5 or RHEL 5, but you have CentOS 7 installed.  The major versions are not compatible.

The **oldest** version of PostgreSQL available for CentOS 7 is version 9.3.  You can install it with these commands:

```
rpm -iUvh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm
yum -y install postgresql93-server
```

The **latest** version of PostgreSQL available for CentOS 7 (at the time of writing) is version 9.4.  You can install it with these commands:

```
rpm -Uvh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.4/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql94-server
```