# Install naemon on CentOS 7?

Tags: installation, centos

I am following these instructions: http://www.naemon.org/documentation/usersguide/quickstart-centos.html

But when I try to "Install Naemon", I have errors:

```
[root@ccnagios naemon-rpm]# yum install *naemon*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining libnaemon-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: libnaemon-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Marking libnaemon-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining naemon-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: naemon-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Marking naemon-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining naemon-core-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: naemon-core-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Marking naemon-core-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining naemon-core-dbg-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: naemon-core-dbg-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Marking naemon-core-dbg-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining naemon-devel-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: naemon-devel-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Marking naemon-devel-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Marking naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining naemon-thruk-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: naemon-thruk-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Marking naemon-thruk-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining naemon-thruk-libs-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: naemon-thruk-libs-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Marking naemon-thruk-libs-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining naemon-thruk-reporting-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: naemon-thruk-reporting-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Marking naemon-thruk-reporting-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libnaemon.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package naemon.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: naemon-tools = 1.0.3-1.el6 for package: naemon-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.copahost.com
 * epel: mirror.fraunhofer.de
 * extras: mirrors.prometeus.net
 * updates: centos.copahost.com
---> Package naemon-core.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package naemon-core-dbg.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package naemon-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package naemon-livestatus.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) for package: naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) for package: naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) for package: naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package naemon-thruk.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package naemon-thruk-libs.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package naemon-thruk-reporting.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64 (/naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64 (/naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: naemon-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64 (/naemon-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: naemon-tools = 1.0.3-1.el6
Error: Package: naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64 (/naemon-livestatus-1.0.3-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is pretty much the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/a/884324/83694).

The instructions you followed were for CentOS 6, but you are running CentOS 7, which is not compatible.

The CentOS 7 packages for Naemon are located [here](https://labs.consol.de/naemon/release/v1.0.3/rhel7/x86_64/).

Make sure you undo the steps you followed in the CentOS 6 guide before trying the CentOS 7 installation.

---

### Additional Help

Try following these in order to rid your system of the incompatible CentOS 6 packages and install Naemon for CentOS 7 (I have not tested these instructions):

#### Remove `epel-release` for CentOS 6

```
yum erase -y epel-release
```

#### Install `epel-release` for your current operating system (CentOS 7)

```
yum install -y epel-release
```

#### Download the CentOS 7 Naemon packages

```
mkdir naemon ; cd naemon
wget -A rpm -mpEkKnp -nd https://labs.consol.de/naemon/release/v1.0.3/rhel7/x86_64/
```

#### Install the CentOS 7 Naemon packages

```
yum install *.rpm
cd ..
```